# In Pinescript, how to save math.min() or array.min() price?

Tags: algorithm, pine-script, pine-script-v5, candlestick-chart

Is there any way to save either math.min() or array.min() price? Every time my algo recognizes a candle pattern and a breakdown from math.min() happens the candle after, that's the only time it goes in the bar after the candle pattern for a trade. Is there a way to save the price so that the algo can wait until market price hits it to take a trade if there's no breakdown right after? Or am I just doing this wrong?

Thanks for the help in advance!

```
//@version=5
strategy("Entry Price", overlay=true)

var float entryprice = na
var lows = array.new_float()

if close[2] > open[2] and close[1] < open[1] and strategy.position_size == 0
    entryprice := math.min(low[2], low[1])
    array.push(lows, entryprice)

plot(array.min(lows), title='Entry', color=color.new(color.purple, 0), style=plot.style_stepline_diamond)

if close > array.min(lows)
    array.push(lows, low)

if close <= array.min(lows)
    strategy.entry("Go Short", strategy.short, qty=1, oca_type=strategy.oca.cancel)
```

The idea is to have the array "lows" have the elements initially with the min price of the last 2 bars and if there's no breakdown, to add the last current price to the array until it hits min price. Unless there's an easier way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you store them in `var` variables?

Comment: I just tried that but it's still the same...

Comment: Could you please update your code?